# How can I send an HTTP GET request from the command line under WinPE?

Tags: curl, winpe

I need to send an [HTTP GET request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) under [Windows Preinstallation Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) (WinPE).

My first thought was curl.exe. It works well under Windows, but not WinPE. I committed curl.exe to boot.wim, but when I tested it under WinPE, it returns nothing. I have tested wget.exe in the same way as well, and it works well. But wget.exe was used to download a file, not to send an HTTP request.

How do I make curl.exe work under WinPE? Or is there another way to send an HTTP request under WinPE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wget will use a GET request to retrieve whatever URL you feed to it, unless specified otherwise.

Another way would be to telnet into port 80 of your server and issue the http command directly.

From a command line window:

```
telnet <yourserver> 80
GET <path>
```

You might need to issue some additional http requests depending on how your server is configured. Read up on [http headers](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/http.html) for more detailed information on this.

Comment: Unfortunately, telnet is not supported in WinPE as also. But as you mentioned, wget will trigger a GET request. So I use "wget -t1 -T3 my-url" in my case and it works through not an elegant way. Thanks